# Two way binding on angular material slide toggle not working as expected (Angular 4)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

I have implemented the angular material slide-toggle that all seems to work except for some reason it isn't binding the value to the relevant variable for some reason?

```
// other irrevelant imports above..
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.scss'],
    host: {
     '(document:click)': 'handleClickEvent($event)',
  }
})

export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {

  filteringSchedule: boolean = false;
  filteringSent: boolean = false;
  filteringFailed: boolean = false;
}
```

// component

```
<mat-slide-toggle
    class="calendar-filter-types"
    [ngModel]="(filteringSchedule)"
    [color]=""
    [checked]="">
    Scheduled : {{ filteringSchedule }}
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Once I check or uncheck the toggle I would expect the `filteringSchedule` value to change to true or false accordingly? However within the component it always stays as `false` for some unknown reason - can anyone suggest why is this?

I am Angular 4

Comment: Just looking at your code and you can just declare your boolean values like this:
 filteringSchedule = false;
  filteringSent = false;
  filteringFailed = false;
as typescript implicitely cast values, it will be boolean.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just update your html to

```
[(ngModel)]="filteringSchedule"
```

Comment: @Zabs no probs :) glad to help

Comment: also import `FormsModule` in your module

Answer (score 2):

```
[ngModel]="(filteringSchedule)"
```

Change this to:

```
[(ngModel)]="filteringSchedule"
```

Answer (score 2):

This works on Angular8+

```
[(ngModel)]="filteringSchedule"
```

And make sure you already imported FormsModule

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
```